# Discord.py | How can I make the bot tag the owner of the guild on joining the guild?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

My code:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self, guild):
    general = find(lambda x: x.name == "general", guild.text_channels)
    if general and general.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:
        await general.send(f"Beep Boop. I've hopped on the server! {guild.owner}, "
                           f"it is advised that you run `.setup` command")
```

On joining the guild, the bot says: `Beep Boop. I've hopped on the server! foobar#1234, it is advised that you run .setup command`
Foobar#1234 being the guild owner in this case. I've tried adding @ before `{guild.owner}` as well so that it would look like

```py
await general.send(f"Beep Boop. I've hopped on the server! @{guild.owner}, "
                   f"it is advised that you run `.setup` command")
```

It doesn't actually tag the owner of the guild. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`guild.owner.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention).